# BeautifulSoup does not extract commet tags in dynamic page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**What I need:** Count the number of reviews under an extension in *Chrome Store* in all languages.
**What I did:** Tried BeautifulSoup to extract a certain tag. I reserched the html-code of the page and found a review tag:
[image]

Tried this code:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html5lib')
    comments = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'ba-bc-Xb ba-ua-zl-Xb')
```

But `print(comments)` shows that the array **is empty**.
I am stuck at the moment and I see that further I need to handle *two problems*:

1. How to cope with select language buttom? How to count reviews in *all* languages if by default only one language is selected.
   [image: selecting certain language]
2. The reviews are stored in different tabs. I read about dynamically extract it but didn't get a point.

[image: different tabs]

Comment: I guess you should add page number and required language to your URL as parameters, but it depends on how server set to send data

Comment: Can you provide the initial URL for testing?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/evernote-web-clipper/pioclpoplcdbaefihamjohnefbikjilc?hl=en       for ex

Answer (score 0):

You could use selenium to perform the tasks and waits for page changes and extract the review count from the `PaginationMessage`. Tested with a few links. You may need to add error handling for items with no reviews. There also seems to be some POST XHR activity yielding review JSON strings that you may wish to explore.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

url = 'https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/evernote-web-clipper/pioclpoplcdbaefihamjohnefbikjilc?hl=en/'
#url = 'https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/https-everywhere/gcbommkclmclpchllfjekcdonpmejbdp?hl=en/'
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get(url)
WebDriverWait(d, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, ':21'))).click()
ActionChains(d).click_and_hold(WebDriverWait(d, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.h-z-Ba-ca.ga-dd-Va.g-aa-ca')))).perform()
languageSelection = WebDriverWait(d, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.g-aa-ca-ma-x-L')))
languageSelection[1].click()

s= WebDriverWait(d, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.Aa.dc-tf + span'))).text
print(s.split()[-1])
d.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The result is 110 what is equals to the number of reviews on the first tab in russian, I need to count overall number of reviews in all languages.

Comment: 168. It's still not the overall number. But I'm grateful for your work. When it script is performed I see how Chrome browser works in real time (it opens and turn pages on its own) but if the number of tabs are very big - it means that I need to wait a lot of time the webdriver to extract it.

Comment: I'm confused. If I use your link and go to the reviews tab and select all languages I see 168 as the number of reviews. What is the expected number?

Comment: The number is much bigger. If you push 'Next' constantly you'll see that the number is rising higher.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/evernote-web-clipper/pioclpoplcdbaefihamjohnefbikjilc?hl=en')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, ':21'))).click()
wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.h-z-Ba-ca.ga-dd-Va.g-aa-ca'))
    ).click()

english = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="ah-mg-j"]/span').text
print('English: ' + english.split()[-1])

wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="g-aa-ca-ma-x-L" and text() = "All languages"]'))
    ).click()
wait.until_not(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="ah-mg-j"]/span'), english))
time.sleep(2)

AllCount = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="ah-mg-j"]/span').text
print('All languages: ' + AllCount.split()[-1])
driver.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for help. It returns:`English: 128
All languages: 168` It's not the total number on all tabs